# progress bar showing progess scrolling down page reaches end before page does

Tags: jquery, css, progress-bar

I have a progress bar to show where the reader is when they're scrolling down the web page. The bar seems to work find on short pages. But on long pages, it reaches the end before the user has scrolled to the end. Can anyone tell me what's going wrong please?

html:

```
<progress value="0"></progress>
```

css:

```
progress {
  /* Positioning */
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 75px;

  /* Dimensions */
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;

  /* Reset the appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;

  /* Get rid of the default border in Firefox/Opera. */
  border: none;

  /* Progress bar container for Firefox/IE10+ */
  background-color: transparent;

  /* Progress bar value for IE10+ */
  color: #c19566;

  z-index: 9999;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: transparent;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: #c19566;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: #c19566;
}
```

jquery:

```
var winHeight = $(window).height(),
    docHeight = $(document).height(),
    progressBar = $('progress'),
                        max, value;

    /* Set the max scrollable area */
    max = docHeight - winHeight;
    progressBar.attr('max', max);

    $(document).on('scroll', function(){
        value = $(window).scrollTop();
        progressBar.attr('value', value);
    });
```